# TypeScript complains about existing Vue component property defined with vue-property-decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, tslint

I have a Vue component that has a property defined using a decorator:

```js
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator"
@Component({
             props: {
               myId: String,
             },
           })
class TestProp extends Vue {
  myFunction(obj: any) {
    return obj[this.myId] // here tslint complains: "Property 'myId' does not exist on type 'TestProp'."
  }
}
```

I can avoid the type error by converting `this` to `any`:

```js
  myFunction(obj: any) {
    return obj[(this as any).myId]
  }
```

But this is rather a work around than a solution.

I guess compiler isn't aware of the properties defined by the `@Component` decorator?

Any ideas?

Comment: please share complete error details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use this library: https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator

With this you can declare your prop inside your component class.

For example:

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
class TestProp extends Vue {
  @Prop(String) myId: string!
}
```

Comment: I added the other answer, but this is what I was looking for and didn't find. Vue needs to convert to this way instead of a single decorator

Comment: This way to declare properties is really nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [TypeScript example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blob/master/example/src/App.vue) states that you must document them yourself in the component.

From that page

```
  // additional declaration is needed
  // when you declare some properties in `Component` decorator
```

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator"
@Component({
  props: {
    myId: String,
  },
})
class TestProp extends Vue {

  myId: string;

  myFunction(obj: any) {
    return obj[this.myId] // here tslint complains: "Property 'myId' does not exist on type 'TestProp'."
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing at this example. However, in the example the `propMessage` isn't declared again in the class ...

Comment: It is wrong in that example, it won't compile of you use it